# Which one is correct, "best wishes to you" or "best wishes for you"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-for

Which one is correct, "best wishes *to* you" or "best wishes *for* you"?

Comment: Typically in such a greeting, the addressee follows ***to*** and the occasion follows ***for*** or ***on***. 'Best Wishes to the Bride & Groom'; 'Best Wishes for the New Year'.

Comment: I asked a related question recently: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93272/is-free-education-to-all-correct

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They have slightly different meanings.

> Best wishes to you

means I am sending you my best wishes, while

> Best wishes for you

means I have best wishes in my heart for you.

The first form is the standard in letters and cards, for example.

Comment: @Amirouche -- I agree with this one; they technically mean different things, but they serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 9):

**Best wishes to you** is correct. I've never heard a native English speaker say "best wishes for you", and there are [no examples of "best wishes for you" in the British National Corpus](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=best%20wishes%20for%20you).

"Best wishes for 2011" or "best wishes for the new year" are fine. For more examples, see [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22best+wishes+for%22) or the [British National Corpus](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=best%20wishes%20for).

Comment: +1 Thank's for your response, I want just tell you that one times I have helped using google I was downvoted :( http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4419/in-the-internet-and-on-the-internet/6518#6518

Comment: @Jasper: yes, good point. +1.

Answer (score 6):

> Best wishes to you

- is the more usual construction of the two.

You can *wish for* something (using wish as a verb) or you can send a *wish to* someone (using wish as a noun). Combining these constructions is an error.

Answer (score 5):

Simply:

- ".. best wishes to you..."
- "best wishes for **your**..."

In the first instance, *towards* is the connotation that *to* is meant to take. (It so happens also to be an annotated meaning.)

In the second, *for* has no connoted sense of directionality but, instead, connotes application or bestowal--hence the change to possessive of "your..."

In one instance "wishes" extend towards the second person; in the second to something possessed or conferred by the second person.

Word meaning, not grammar, is the more fitting tag. Possibly syntax as well.