# Is "free education to all" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

At the time of writing, there is a group of Cooper Union students [protesting](http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/2012/12/cooper_union_free_tuition.php) the university's [decision to charge tuition](http://blogs.villagevoice.com/runninscared/2011/11/cooper_union_co.php). They are holding a banner that reads:

> Free Education to All

Can this be construed as correct (under any scheme of interpretation)? It seems that "Free Education *for* All" would be expected, but I wonder if using "to" here is also correct (perhaps with a different meaning).

Comment: 'Death to all infidels' and 'A Merry Christmas to all our Members' use _to_; they've got perhaps more poignancy, more va-va-voom than the for- alternatives would have. These are not complete sentences, so inviolable 'rules' are even harder to claim. Can we think of a sensible unellipted form? 'Free Education should / must be made available to All.' Is it having a desired effect? Making us think about the issue? Making us examine the English and the issue behind it? Making us wonder if these students really need some free education? Would a 'Free Education for All' banner do the same?

Comment: Are you yourself a Cooper Union student seeking a wider audience? Is the clever variant yours?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I'm not one of the students, no, but my office is near Cooper Union and we all saw the banner; there was some discussion about whether or not it was a correct wording.

Comment: It's far better than _Education Free for All_, which may be the reality anyway. :-)

Comment: @Ben: Forgive my suspicious mind (though I'd probably have done it as a student). I can't shake the resonance of the reformed Scrooge's "A merry Christmas to everybody!" - and wasn't Dickens inspired when he hired the Muppets to star in the dramatisation of "A Christmas Carol" - and the fact that you'd have to be almost a Christmasphobe to ignore the students' poignant appeal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'[Give] free education **to** all' seems like an imperative: '*[You, the institution]* must give *free education to all*', as opposed to 'Demand *free education **for** all*'.

But, because the leading verb is omitted, the banner's meaning is unclear. Who are they talking to? I assume that they are targeting both students and members of the institution and therefore, as pointed out by Ryan, they should instead use the standard idiom: Free Education for All.

[To see an example of usage over 20 years ago](http://www.unesco.org/en/efa/the-efa-movement/world-conference-on-efa-jomtien-1990.)

Answer (score 1):

Standard American English idiom would certainly be *Free Education for All*. *To all* sounds stilted to native ears, and probably in the UK, Australia, etc., as well.