# Do you say content is in a website or on a website?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“On website” or “at website”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/on-website-or-at-website)
>   [Which of these is correct: “Sheila is now in Facebook” or “Sheila is now on Facebook”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24800/which-of-these-is-correct-sheila-is-now-in-facebook-or-sheila-is-now-on-face)

Which is best in your opinion?

"You can find this content on the X website."
"You can find this content in the X website."

"I posted the comment on FB."
"I posted the comment in FB."

Thanks for your opinions and advice!

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4419/in-the-internet-vs-on-the-internet

Comment: Also related: [When should I use “in” or “on”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-in-or-on)

Comment: I don't see a previous question that combines the words “in”, “on”, and “website”, but the two suggestions above plus  [Search this website or search in this website](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43226),  [On website or at website](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8226), and  [This question has been asked at stack overflow vs on stack overflow](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491) cover the bases.  Current question duplicates effect of previous questions.

Answer (score 13):

Both appear to be grammatically and logically correct. Something can be **in** the text of a site or appear **in** the images of a site. Similarly something can appear **on** the screen of your device showing the website.

However, [usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20a%20website,on%20a%20website&year_start=1990&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) seems to strongly favor **on a website**.

[image: website ngram]

Comment: I don't think that _Something can be **in** the text of a site_ being correct means that _Something can be **on** the site_ is correct as well, because the text and the site are two different concepts. As an analogy, _I can be **in** my car_, but that doesn't mean that _I am **in** the highway_. Neither is the car. We are both **on** the highway.

Comment: @Supr I have often heard discussions about material that is not on the first page being described as *buried deep **in** the website*, that is a portion of the website that you must *dig* to get to. There are a number of *digging* and *mining* analogies that are used in connection with web-based data. There is also the logical analysis that recognizes that all material the website displays is contained **in** the code.  Notwithstanding, I think **on** is more common.

Comment: That I have to agree with, but your original argument still doesn't sound right to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think *on the website* and *on Facebook* are what you would normally find.

Answer (score 1):

For normal usage, "on the website" sounds more correct to me, because you're reading information off of the user interface. For usage in **A** pplication **P** rogramming **I** nterfaces, there's a solid argument to be made for there being information "in a website", because you're making requests that go into a server to fetch content, instead of having it displayed for your consumption. I answered [this related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/82872/24443) similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Websites seem to be treated in standard English as equivalent to notice-boards, rather than books.

So where you would say "I found that handy fact in the Encyclopaedia Britannica.", it is more normal to say that "I found the answer to that on Wikipedia."
This could perhaps follow from the term web-page - after all, content which is (admittedly) in a book can be found on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forgot about another two-letter preposition that could be used: *at*.

> The information can be found on the website.
>   The information can be found at the website.
>   The information can be found in the website.

These are [all in use](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20the%20website,on%20our%20website,at%20the%20website,at%20our%20website,in%20the%20website,in%20our%20website&year_start=1990&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), apparently.

Oftentimes, more than one preposition is suitable to convey something like this.

That's all I have time to post for now – supper's at the table.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like neither "in" nor "on" is right or wrong (sorry, I just can't get my head around "at"!) Maybe I'll just keep using "in" till enough people follow my lead :-)