# The correct preposition with "Google play store" and "Google"

Tags: idioms, prepositions, computing

I'm a bit confused about using the correct preposition in the following sentences.

Which one sounds correct?

> 1. On the Google play store
> 2. In the Google play store

What about the following examples?

> 3. Search on/in the Google ...
> 4. Find it in/on the Google ...

I searched *[on the Google](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22on+the+google%22)* and *[in the Google](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22in+the+google%22)* and it seems people use them both.

Which of the following is more idiomatic?

> 1. You can search the google play store
> 2. You can find it in the google play store
> 3. It's in the google play store.
> 4. You can find it on google play.

Does the preposition "in" sound better to you with "the", and "on" sounds better without the definite article?

In that example would you only say "in the" with "store" and "on" without "store"?

Comment: Related question, [“In the Internet” vs. “on the Internet”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4419/in-the-internet-vs-on-the-internet)

Comment: What about "at the Google Play Store"? "within the Google Play Store"?  Generally, I think, nowadays we can treat places in the digital world with the same language as used for places in the analog world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of online stores is a relatively new phenomenon and I'm not sure that there is an accepted grammatical usage for your initial example. An online store is not something that one can physically enter, yet we speak both of "logging in" and logging on" to a computer system or an Internet site.

Regarding your second example, I would use "on Amazon" instead of "in Amazon," yet I have used both "in Google" and "on Google." However, I wouldn't put "the" in front of either version. But I would use "the iTunes Store."

I suspect that this type of usage will be covered by a publication's house style. If you are writing for yourself, go with what sounds best to you.